# How to support distinctUntilChanged for Binder in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I made a simple Rx extension for `FloatRatingView` library for its `rating` property, like so:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

public extension Reactive where Base: FloatRatingView {

    /// Bindable sink for `rating` property
    public var rating: Binder<Double?> {
        return Binder(self.base) { frv, attr in
            frv.rating = attr ?? 0
        }
    }
}
```

Question is, how do I make that extension support the `.distinctUntilChanged()`?

My idea is I need to have a throttle or debounce before passing the value of the rating to the controller, like so:

```
    self.ratingView_Driver.rx.rating
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debounce(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe { _ in

        }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Error is:

> Value of type 'Binder' has no member 'distinctUntilChanged'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your view has `rating` property.

```
extension Reactive where Base: FloatRatingView {
    var rating: Observable< Double > {
        return self.observeWeakly(Double.self, #keyPath(FloatRatingView.rating)).map { $0 ?? 0 }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
self.ratingView.rx.rating
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debounce(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe { _ in

        }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```